# Creating Views on a Sybase ASE database from a stored procedure on a different database on the same server?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to create a view on a database from a second database using a stored procedure.  I can create the stored procedure with the SQL below if I run this on the target database:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('databasename..v_MyView') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW v_MyView
GO

CREATE VIEW v_MyView
AS      

    select FirstName, LastName, Address
    from databasename..t_UserTable
    where SalesPersonId = 21563 

GO
```

I was hoping I could just prefix the line:

```
CREATE VIEW v_MyView
```

with:

```
CREATE VIEW databasename..v_MyView
```

and then call this from inside a stored procedure on a second database on the same server but this does not work.

The error back from DBViz is:

```
 16:26:28  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 166, SQL State: S1000]  CREATE        VIEW does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.
```

... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]

Any ideas or suggestions please?

ASE 15.0, jTDS Type 4 JDBC Driver for MS SQL Server and Sybase, 1.2.7

Comment: Change your SP in DB1 to call a SP in DB2 which then creates the view?

Comment: The problem is it is a UAT db and the entire db gets deleted and overwritten with the PROD instance including all SPs.  I then want to add the view to the UAT instance.

Comment: Interesting, I'm running ASE 15.5, and it won't let me create a view inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the following stored procedure and put it in sybsystemprocs:

```
create procedure sp_user_create_view 
    @a_view_name        varchar(255),
    @a_view_query       varchar(16000)    
as
begin
    if object_id(@a_view_name) is not null
    begin
        exec ('drop view ' + @a_view_name) 
    end

    exec ('create view ' + @a_view_name + ' as ' + @a_view_query) 
end
go
grant execute on sp_user_create_view to <user/group/role as appropriate>
go
```

Then switch your starting database, in my case testdb and execute:

```
use testdb
go
exec tempdb..sp_user_create_view object_name, 'select name from sysobjects'
go
```

This will create the view 'object_name' in tempdb.

```
use tempdb
go
set rowcount 5
go
select * from object_name
go
name
----------------
object_name      
sysalternates
sysattributes
syscolumns
syscomments

(5 rows affected)
set rowcount 0
go
```

This was tested on Sybase ASE 15.7